# Install OneNote 2016 on Windows 10

Tags: windows, windows-10, microsoft-onenote, microsoft-onenote-2016

I have Windows 10 with OneNote pre-installed, but it's a very lightweight version of the real OneNote 2016.

How can I install OneNote 2016? If I go to www.onenote.com to install the full version, it says that OneNote was already shipped with Windows 10.

I have read that there is a difference between OneNote and OneNote 2016 (and 2010, 2013, etc.), and in the lightweight version, it seems I cannot insert equations, customize the layout, etc.

Answer (score 4):

> I have read that there is a difference between OneNote and OneNote
>   2016 (and 2010, 2013, etc.), and in the lightweight version, it seems
>   I cannot insert equations, customize the layout, etc.

There is indeed a difference:

> [image]
>
> [image]

[What's the difference between OneNote and OneNote 2016](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/What-s-the-difference-between-OneNote-and-OneNote-2016-a624e692-b78b-4c09-b07f-46181958118f)

> How can I install OneNote 2016? If I go to www.onenote.com to install
>   the full version, it says that OneNote was already shipped with
>   Windows 10.

You can download OneNote 2016 at [here](https://www.onenote.com/Download), despite what the website says, you are eventually sent to the executable download.

[Download OneNote 2016](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=49124)

Answer (score 1):

Microsoft have further obfuscated the downloading of Office 2016 Onenote.  The only place I could find at Microsoft was [here (32-bit)](http://www.onenote.com/download/win32/x32/en-us) and [here (64-bit)](http://www.onenote.com/download/win32/x64/en-us).  These currently redirect to these download links (though for how long remains to be seen).
https://c2rsetup.officeapps.live.com/c2r/download.aspx?productReleaseID=OneNoteFreeRetail&platform=x86&language=en-us&version=O16GA&Source=O16ONF and
https://c2rsetup.officeapps.live.com/c2r/download.aspx?productReleaseID=OneNoteFreeRetail&platform=x64&language=en-us&version=O16GA&Source=O16ONF

These versions of the programs are very keen for you to login to a school/business account - I had to fiddle around to get it working with my personal MS account.

You can also download these from Softpedia, as well as an Office iso from there (although I've not tried that).

Access via the links in other current answers doesn't work for me.

Despite MS's promise to provide the same functionality in the MS Store version of OneNote, there remain significant differences e.g. tags are not fully supported - search is expected next month, and it looks as though the facility to save to local filestore will never appear.

Answer (score -1):

Microsoft has hidden the download link somewhat recently, which *could* mean, that this version will not be there forever. But as for now you still find it here:

http://www.onenote.com/download

**Ignore** the big message which says that you already have OneNote installed.

Scroll down to <<**Also available on**>>

Click on the link "**Windows Desktop**" in this section to download the installer.

Comment: “Windows Desktop” isn’t listed in that section.  Unless your saying the linked you provided is the desktop version.  Which is the same link I provided over a year ago.